# Construct DFA for the following language on Σ={a,b}

Tags: automata

Construct DFA for the following language on Σ={a,b}.

L={w:|w|mod 4=0}

i have the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your DFA is correct. It is not minimal for the language it accepts, but it accepts the right language. A smaller eliminates state q4 since it is equivalent to state q0; then, the states q0, q1, q2 and q3 correspond to having processed a prefix of the input whose length is congruent to 0, 1, t and 3, respectively, modulo 4.

Answer (score 0):

The `DFA` you made is correct;
As language strings should have length(4 or multiple of 4);
and what you made is correct; as it is also accepting when length gets minimum 4; on final state if again you apply input; 
it again goes away from final state until length become multiple of **4**.